# Plot histogram(change axis)

Tags: image, excel, matlab, image-processing

I have n*2 matrix for example matrix A.First column is some index and the second one is the histogram.I want to visualise only the nonzero histogram,so, I filtered A and deleted the index with histogram zero. I use

```
 bar(A(:,1),A(:,2))
```

I didn't use excel. How can I plot it in excel?

This is my data (so I want to display only the elements of this matrix but as you see in figure it display all index from zero to end in x axis and I want to display only the index of nonzero values in x axis)

```
    1   0.0573770000000000
    2   0.622951000000000
    3   0.0819672000000000
    4   0.0491803000000000
    5   0.0409836000000000
    6   0.00819672000000000
    7   0.00819672000000000
    8   0.0163934000000000
    10  0.00819672000000000
    12  0.00819672000000000
    14  0.00819672000000000
    19  0.0163934000000000
    34  0.00819672000000000
    50  0.00819672000000000
    54  0.00819672000000000
    62  0.00819672000000000
    175 0.00819672000000000
    410 0.00819672000000000
   1178 0.00819672000000000
   1193 0.00819672000000000
   1669 0.00819672000000000
```

It has very bad visualisation.Is it possible in matlab or I should use another software?
[image: My data]

The result of Roney answer in my data. (I want the real label from my data below each bar in x axis.)

[image: The result of Roney answer]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the you want the non-zero bars to be displayed without gaps between them for the zero values, you can do the following:

```
>> non_zero = A(:,2) ~= 0;
>> bar(A(non_zero,2))
>> set(gca, 'XTick', 1:sum(non_zero));    %New code.
>> set(gca, 'XTickLabel', num2str(A(non_zero,1)));
```

For say,

```
>> 
A = [
1 0.001
2 0.005
4 0
5 0.003
];
```

The resultant figure would be:

[image]

For your data, the result would be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. your example is correct but it doesn't work for my data. I add my data to the question.

Comment: @Fatime: I've added an extra line to my code. It should work well now.

Comment: Thanks,It works.But the labels have bad visualisation. Can I change the label of x axis vertically for better visualisation?

Comment: @Fatime: You can. This is something I was struggling with myself recently. MATLAB does not allow you to do that easily, but I was able to use [this](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotate-x-axis-tick-labels) to do so. just give `rotateXLabels(gca, -90)` after the figure has been generated as above.

Comment: @Fatime: Also, do consider accepting the answer if your question is resolved. This marks the question as solved and may benefit the community in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I voted the answer and I accept it now because it solved completely.